# routing the network over ipv4 instead of ipv6 in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipv6

I am using the 3rd party library which only support ipv4.
Whenever there is ipv6 network in my iOs device 3rd party fail.Is there any way I can force or convert or create ipv4 network and do routineg of the application in ipv4 instead of ipv6.
I found the below link but don't know how to implement it or does apple will approve that. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/neipv4route

Any help on this please

Comment: Are you going to submit this to Apple for review?  If so then you will need to support IPv6.  Apple reviews apps in an IPv6 environment and will reject apps that do not work in that environment.  `NEIPv4Route` won't help; It is used in Network Extensions that create VPN tunnels.

Comment: you should name the library you are using so we might offer alternatives. I dont believe there is a way for you to make "network" internal to your device and bridge it to the external ipv6 network. Even if there were its a poor hack and you should seek an actual solution.

Comment: @BradAllred thank you for the quick reply. Library is pjsip. It does support ipv6 but server don't support ipv4. problem is when ipv6 network try to communicate with the server with ipv4 it give me error -  stunresolve  Failed in pj_dns_srv_resolve(): No working DNS nameserver (PJLIB_UTIL_EDNSNOWORKINGNS) . So I am thinking to change the routing to ipv4 and this will work

Comment: No, change your server to support IPv6.  Even if you could prefer IPv4 what happens when your app runs on a pure IPv6 network?

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you for the reply. I can change the server to ipv6. But when there are two network available I want to give preference to ipv4. and is there any solution for that ?

Comment: It doesn't work that way. When both IPv4 and IPv6 are available, the preference is for IPv6.

Answer (score 2):

I think you’ve answered your own question.  The library your using only supports ipv4.  So either you need to find a library that supports ipv6 or write your own since you can’t control what the network is broadcasting.

Apple has a write up on this here :  [supporting ipv6](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1)